# Sorting DateTime column in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have an ASP.NET MVC app where I have a column in a table that displays DateTime values from a MySQL database. The column gets sorted by string value instead of `DateTime` value. I need it to display like Friday, August 14th, 2020 05:13 PM.

I get it to display like this using

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]
```

I need it to sort by Date/Time. This is the code I have.

DataView:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]                               
public System.DateTime JobDateTime { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.jobs.OrderByDescending(x=>x.JobDateTime).ToList());
}
```

Index view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobDateTime)`
```

I can't figure out how to sort it and get it to display in long date format. I've only been able to get one or the other.

Comment: When you get data from DB, then DateTime is sorting in string format?

Comment: Yes it's sorting the column as strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MassDateTime` property would be in a ViewModel (most probably).
Let we call it as `JobViewModel` or adjust the name whatever you have given to it.

Then the field `MassDateTime` type should be `string` instead of `DateTime` as required to show on view in string format.

```
public class JobViewModel
{
    public string MassDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

No need to mention attribute on the property.

Now `Index` method would be like as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = db.jobs.
                 AsEnumerable().
                 OrderByDescending(x => x.JobDateTime).
                 Select(a => new JobViewModel
                    {
                        MassDateTime = a.JobDateTime.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm")
                    }).ToList();

    return View(data);    
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't solve my problem of sorting by string instead of date.

Comment: Where is the issue now? Its working my side and sorting the dates properly

Comment: I get an exception: System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: @steven85791 Answer is updated, probably would resolve your exception error.

Comment: Now it throws another exception: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Church_Musician_Administration_App__Updated_.Models.JobViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Database_Access.job]'.`

Comment: Then simply change `AsEnumerable()` to `ToList()`

Comment: @steven85791 Is it done or not? Another solution for this exception is that: Keep `AsEnumerable()` there in the query and use `IEnumerable` type instead of `List` in your view page to pass `JobViewModel` on top of page.

Comment: I tried what you said and It compiles and when I run it it is still sorting by String and not by Date. I have Friday, July 17, 2020 10:00 PM and the next entry is Friday, May 15, 2020 10:00 AM which is incorrect. And with this query, it doesn't give me any of my other columns in the chart. They're all blank except the DateTime one.

Comment: If you or anyone check this solution to run in separate Console application, would find no issue. After I have provided everything, I don't know about your context that what is your problem.

Comment: Your solution did work. I had a problem with my javascript in my view. I adjusted the javascript and now it works fine. Thank you for your help! I marked it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `DisplayFormat` attribute is applied before sorting. In this case, you might want to remove it from the property definition, and put into your *Linq* query:

```
db.jobs.OrderByDescending(x => x.JobDateTime).Select(d => d.ToString("f")).ToList()
```

Or do that transformation in Razor, whichever suits you best.

Comment: I tried using what you suggested but when I use it, it throws an exception saying "No overload method for "ToString" takes 1 arguments. Am I missing something?

Comment: After reading some other similar questions, I also tried the query this way and it still gave me the same error `db.jobs.OrderByDescending(x => x.JobDateTime).ToList().Select(d => d.ToString("f"))`

Comment: Are you sure `JobDateTime` is of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes it’s DateTime. I double checked

Comment: Oh, I oversaw something.
Use `Select(d => d.JobDateTime.ToString("f"))`
When you use `OrderBy`, you still get the original entity back. So you should probably keep the lambda variable name as `x` to not get confused the way I was :-)